# How to write a Pester test to see if script succeeds to change a firewall rule without actually changing my firewall rules?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a script that all it does is changing a list of firewall rules/profiles. I'd like to write unit tests for that script without messing my firewall rules.

This script runs on a VM.

I'm using Pester for testing.

Comment: Your question needs a specific issue / an attempt at some code to be suitable for StackOverflow, but (to help get you started) the technique you need to use is Mocking: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking

Comment: When you mock a command in Pester, make sure you're dot-sourcing your functions, not just importing them with ipmo. That has gotten me more than a few times.

Comment: I don't know how to approach this. My code interacts with OS. How do I make sure my code did what's supposed to do to OS settings without actually messing the OS settings? And if I mock the cmdlets, well, how is this reflection of the actual settings that I'd like to make sure they actually got changed by my code!